# дублирующиеся запросы в базу от gridview в yii2

Tags: yii2

Есть Поставщик (Provider) и у него есть в профиле некие свойства, одно из них 'wuo'. Не  суть важно, что это такое.
Есть список товаров, которые могут принадлежать разным Поставщикам. С помощью greedview я строю таблицу, где одним из участков кода является следующее:

```
                [
                'attribute' => 'available',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'headerOptions' => ['width' => '6%'],
                'value' => function($model) {
                   $model->user->providerProfile->wuo == 0 ? $wuo = 0 : $wuo = 1;
                   if ($model->available == 0) {
                       if ($wuo == 0) {
                            $res = '<span class="label label-danger">'.$model->available.'</span>'; 
                       } else {
                            $res = '<span class="label label-success">'.$model->available.'</span>'; 
                       }
                   } else {
                       $res = '<span class="label label-success">'.$model->available.'</span>';
                   }
                   return $res;
                }

            ],
```

Как видите, в зависимости от значения свойства 'wuo' в профиле Поставщика мне надо вывести тем или иным образом количество (available).

Для построение каждой строки таблицы greedview каждый раз делает запрос в базу в Профиль поставщика создаваю кучу одинаковых запросов http://joxi.ru/ZrJlMXLT9VBY82

Как можно избежать дублирования запросов в данном случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы виджет не делал много запросов в базу, необходимо указать реляцию в методе `->with('relationName')` при подготовке запроса. Это называется жадная загрузка данных.
Жадная загрузка одной связи:

```
$customers = Customer::find()->with('orders')->all();
```

Жадная загрузка нескольких связей:

```
$customers = Customer::find()->with('orders', 'country')->all();
```

Возможно, в данном случае необходимо реализовать жадную загрузку вложенной связи `user->providerProfile`. Для этого можно использовать такой пример:

```
$customers = Customer::find()->with('orders.items')->all();
```

[Более подробно с описанием](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/db-active-record#lazy-eager-loading)

Также хотел обратить внимание на огород с ифами. Не надо перебарщивать. Попробуй более компактный вариант, например:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'available',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'headerOptions' => ['width' => '6%'],
    'value' => function($model) {
        $labelClass = 'label-success';
        if($model->available == 0 && $model->user->providerProfile->wuo == 0){
            $labelClass = 'label-danger';
        }
        return '<span class="label '.$labelClass.'">'.$model->available.'</span>';
    }
],
```

Comment: мой запрос генерирует непосредственно сам вызов связи 
$model->user->providerProfile->wuo
Помогите мне понять как найти файл, в котором непосредственно строиться запрос в базу, чтоб его поправить

Comment: Если подключен модуль debug, внизу сайта есть панелька. Там можно отыскать запрос. Возле запроса будут пути к файлам и номера строк.